# What are some good resources on integrating web apps with SharePoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, integration

I need to get up to speed on various ways to integrate ASP.Net C# web apps with SharePoint. From the most loosely coupled (just pull a bit of content from SharePoint) to full bidirectional sync, version control, workflow, etc.

What are some links or books that can quickly get me oriented as to best options and approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure if this is helpful for you or not, but "[Deployment for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 technology](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=115666)" free ebook may help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious, Microsoft actually has tried to make the documentation for SharePoint 3 much better than versions past.

- TechNet: [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288070.aspx)
- MSDN: [Windows SharePoint Services Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx)
- MSDN: [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441339.aspx)
- MSDN: [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931737.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For a good book, check out Professional SharePoint 2007 Development from Wrox.
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-SharePoint-2007-Development-Programmer/dp/0470117567/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1241998957&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470117567)

The best approach really depends on the requirements are, but there are a number of options with the current technologies.

Comment: I found this book to be largely useless, honestly - there's much more up-to-date information online.

Comment: I've found most books from Wrox to be poorly written, hard to follow, and out-of-date